# How can I insert a value in a specified column together with the other columns without appearing into a new another row?

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010

I am creating a login logout system for our College Library that records the students' time in and time out whenever they enter or exit in our library.

I am using VS 2010 Ultimate for the form and SQL server 2008 r2 for my database.

In my database

i have 3 tables

```
tblCollegeinfo Contains : 
studentNumber(primary key), 
studentName, and 
studentCourse,




tblCollegeStudentLog contains their record with 
studentNumber again as the foreign key, 
studentTimeIn, 
studentTimeOut, 
studentDate and 
LoginNo and 


tblCollegeStudentPassword 
their Passwords with studentNumber again 
and studentPassword.
```

Actually my Log In button works, that whenever they entered their Username and Password and hit the Log In button they are now Logged In and their Student Number, Name, Course Login time (Time In) and Date appears in the ListView.

My problem is the Log out button. I don't know what correct code should i use. What correct SQL query should I use.

I have a hint that I should join the tables first and Insert the Log Out Time as the 'value' in the **studentTimeOut** of the table "**tblCollegeStudentLog**"

but I don't know how. Whenever I click the Log Out button with the SelectedItems in my ListView, instead the Logout Time(Time Out) inserted in the selected item it appears in another row. In short, how can I insert a value in a specified column together with the other columns without appearing into a new another row?

Here's the Code :

```
string query = "SELECT tblCollegeStudentlog.LoginNo,     
                tblCollegeStudentLog.studentNumber, tblCollegeInfo.studentName,     
                tblCollegeInfo.studentCourse, tblCollegeStudentLog.studentTimeIn,     
                tblCollegeStudentLog.studentTimeOut, tblCollegeStudentLog.studentDateIn FROM 

    tblCollegeStudentLog 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblCollegeInfo ON tblCollegeStudentLog.studentNumber = tblCollegeInfo.studentNumber
 WHERE tblCollegeStudentLog.studentNumber = '" + lvwLog.SelectedItems(0).Text + "'";

cmd = New SqlCommand(query, con) cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: Please help me guys to solve this problem :( I hope you understand what I am trying to say :( I want that the inserted Value appears together with the other columns, because what only happens to me is that whenever i hit the Log Out button the value appears in another row alone it is not joining in the other columns :( thanks Guys!!!

Comment: Please share your code whatever you have done till now.

Comment: this is not the right way to share your code @kevingasta.

Comment: Private Sub btnLogoutNow_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnLogoutNow.Click
Connect()

Comment: cmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT tblCollegeStudentlog.LoginNo, tblCollegeStudentLog.studentNumber, tblCollegeInfo.studentName, tblCollegeInfo.studentCourse, tblCollegeStudentLog.studentTimeIn, tblCollegeStudentLog.studentTimeOut, tblCollegeStudentLog.studentDateIn FROM tblCollegeStudentLog LEFT OUTER JOIN tblCollegeInfo ON tblCollegeStudentLog.studentNumber = tblCollegeInfo.studentNumber WHERE  tblCollegeStudentLog.studentNumber = '" + lvwLog.SelectedItems(0).Text + "'", con)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

Comment: If dr.HasRows Then
            cmd = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tblCollegeStudentLog (studentTimeOut) VALUES     ('" + lblTimeOutNya.Text + "') WHERE studentNumber = '" + lvwLog.SelectedItems(0).Text + "' ", con)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MsgBox("You are now logged out!")
        End If

Answer (score 1):

That's not an insert, that's an update.

Example:

```
update
  tblCollegeStudentLog
set
  studentTimeOut = @studentTimeOut
where
  studentNumber = @studentNumber and
  studentTimeOut is null
```

where `@studentNumber` and `@studentTimeOut` are the parameters needed to execute the query.

Comment: This update would overwrite every existing row for a specific student no matter if it'll match any course or login/logout "window". Do not try this code! It's just plain dangerous!

Comment: Sir Pardon me, but if I use the UPDATE one, the student's previous Log Out record (ex. yesterday) will update also, which must not.

Comment: @Lmu92: What are you talkting about? Perhaps you should think before badmouthing others answers?

Answer (score -2):

You'll need to step back and think about the concept in general:
If you want to store login and logout time in one row, how would you deal with the following scenarios:
a) a student didn't login but tries to logout
b) a student did login but never logged out
c) a student logs in multiple time for the same course
...

After finding the answer to each of those questions you can decide wheher it's useful to store login and logout in separate columns or if it's better to have two columns, on representing the time and the other one the "direction" (login or logout)

Comment: thanks Lmu92 that would be very conditional but really gives me an idea :)